# Continuous and bounded variation does not imply absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, bounded-variation, absolute-continuity

I know that a continuous function which is a BV may not be absolutely continuous.  Is there an example of such a function?   I was looking for a BV whose derivative is not Lebesgue integrable but I couldn't find one.

Comment: My apologies; I only saw Byron's when I posted that comment.

Comment: See also" http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499101/example-of-a-function-that-has-the-luzin-n-property-and-is-not-absolutely-cont

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Devil's staircase function does the trick.

Its derivative is almost surely zero with respect to Lebesgue measure,
so the function is not absolutely continuous.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DevilsStaircase.html

Comment: This is indeed the most standard example of a function which has BV but is not AC.  It might be helpful to the OP to know that such a function is (more?) commonly referred to as the Cantor function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function.

Answer (score 10):

Byron already answered your main question, but your last sentence is another matter.  You want a BV function whose derivative is not integrable, but such things don't exist.  In particular, if $f$ is monotone on $[a,b]$, then $f'$ exists a.e., is Lebesgue integrable, and $\int_a^b f' \leq f(b)-f(a)$.  Thus half of the fundamental theorem of calculus holds, so to speak.  General BV functions are differences of monotone functions, so their derivatives are also Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error.