# Borel Measures: Lebesgue Decomposition

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

**Disclaimer**

Please, if you don't like self-answers just avoid this thread.
*(For more details see: [Answer own Question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/98916/79762)*)

**Context**

Given a measure space $\Omega$ with sigma-finite measure $\lambda$.

Consider a finite measure $\kappa<\infty$.

Then there exists a decomposition:
$$\kappa=\kappa_{ac}+\kappa_s\quad(\kappa_{ac}\ll\lambda,\kappa_s\perp\lambda)$$

Moreover the singular measure splits into:
$$\kappa_s=\kappa_{sc}+\kappa_{pp}$$

**Question**

Is the last decomposition w.r.t. singletons or w.r.t. atoms?
*(See the wikipedia articles [Discrete Measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure) and [Atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)).)*

Moreover, can it make a really important difference?
*(I guess so but cannot imagine what...)*

**Remark**

The absolutely continuous measures are characterized precisely by the measurable functions:
$$\kappa_{ac}(E)=\int_Ehd\lambda\quad(h\geq0)$$

Comment: $\mu(\Omega\setminus \{ \omega \in \Omega : \mu\{\omega\}\ne 0 \})=0$. Discrete doesn't make a lot of sense unless you consider the measure of a singleton set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is really into discrete and continuous!**
*(See thread on [Atomic vs. Discrete](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989196/79762) and [Atomic Decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/998313/79762).)*

The reason is that one is tempted to compare the point spectrum to the eigenspaces and that happens to come out fine only if one restricts to measures concentrated on countable sets.