# Borel Measures: Atoms (Summary)

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory, definition

Disclaimer: The question here has been solved, now:

- [Finest Measurable Partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/992289/79762)

*(For jeapardy it is stated below, anyway. Have fun! ;) )*

Summary: This is a summary of the discussions:

- [Measures: Atom Definitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/974065/79762)
- [Borel Measures: Discrete & Continuous Definition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/984724/79762)
- [Borel Measures: Atoms vs. Point Masses](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/987827/79762)

Reference: Further results are accessible from:

- [Wikipedia: Measure Atoms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory))
- [Wikipedia: Discrete Measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_measure)
- [Paper: Decomposition w.r.t. Atoms](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8.pdf)

---

**Definitions**

Call a measure discrete if it is discretely concentrated:
$$\mu(\Omega\setminus\Delta)=0\quad(\#\Delta\leq\aleph_0)$$
and continuous if any discrete has no mass:
$$\#\Delta\leq\aleph_0\implies\mu(\Delta)=0$$
*(Note that I do not require it to decompose into singletons for reason.)*

Call a measure atomic if is made out of atoms only:
$$\mu(\Omega\setminus\bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{A}} A)=0\quad(\mathcal{A}:\text{ atoms})$$
and atomless if it has no atoms at all:
$$\mathcal{A}\text{ empty}\quad(\mathcal{A}:\text{ atoms})$$
*(I have chosen these slightly different formulations for more clarity.)*

**Discussion**

Now, consider a sigma-finite Borel measure $\lambda:\mathcal{B}(\Omega)\to\mathbb{R}_+$.

First, let it be discrete.

Then, by Zorn's lemma it splits into a finest measurable partition.
*(See [Proof to Finest Measurable Partition](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/997257/79762).)*

These are all atoms and therefore it is atomic.

Conversely, let it be atomic.

Then, by sigma-finiteness atoms cannot have infinite mass.
*(See [Last Part of Proof to Measure Atoms: Definitions.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/974290/79762))*

Also, there are at most countably many disjoint ones.

However, they do not need to be countable themselve.
*(See [Example on Atoms vs. Point Masses.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987941/79762))*

Luckily, for separable metric spaces every atom even shrinks to a point mass.
*(See [Proof by Nate Eldredge](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/987851/79762).)*

Thus, it is concentrated on countable set and therefore discrete.

This completes the equivalence!

**Remarks**

Besides, note that the only measure that is both discrete and continuous is the trivial measure.

Similarly, the only measure that is both atomic and atomless is the trivial measure.

**Problem**

Is the first claim of the discussion really true?

Namely, every countable measure space admits a finest measurable partition:
$$\#\Omega\leq\aleph_0:\quad\Omega=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k\quad(A_k\in\Sigma)$$

Comment: You could try something along the lines of considering the equivalence classes under the equivalence relation $x\sim y$ iff for any $A\in\Sigma$, $x\in A\Longleftrightarrow y\in A$. If this works then the equivalence classes are the smallest measurable sets, and define the smallest measurable partition.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Nice idea - seems this works for arbitrary spaces and without Zorn...

Comment: It relies on the underlying set being numerable to prove that the equivalence class is in $\Sigma$, and some form of countable choice to represent the equivalence class as a countable intersection of measurble sets.