# Finest Measurable Partition

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

*Disclaimer: This question is part of: [Borel Measures: Atoms (Summary)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989196/79762)*

Given a sigma algebra $\Sigma$ over a countable space $\#\Omega\leq\aleph_0$.

Does it admit a finest measurable partition:
$$\Omega=\bigsqcup_{k=1}^\infty E_k\quad E_k\in\Sigma$$
*(I guess Zorn's lemma might solve this but not sure about it.)*

Comment: There was already an asnwer but unfortunately it disappeared now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, it does!**

First, fix an element $\omega\in\Omega$.

Then every proper chain has length at most countably infinite:
$$\Omega\supsetneq E_1\supsetneq E_2\supsetneq\ldots\quad\omega\in E_k\in\Sigma$$
and therefore admits a lower bound:
$$\omega\in\bigcap_{k=1}^\infty E_k\in\Sigma$$
Hence, there is a minimal element by Zorn's lemma:
$$\omega\in A_\omega\in\Sigma$$

Now, consider distinct elements $\omega\neq\omega'$.

Assume $A_\omega\cap A_{\omega'}\neq\varnothing$ and $A_\omega\neq A_{\omega'}$.
Also either $\omega\in A_\omega\cap A_{\omega'}$ or $\omega\in A_\omega\cap A_{\omega'}^c$.
So w.l.o.g. $A_\omega\supsetneq A_\omega\cap A_{\omega'}$ with $\omega\in A_\omega\cap A_{\omega'}\in\Sigma$.
But that contradicts minimality.

Concluding, there is a finest measurable partition modulo repetitions:
$$\Omega=\bigsqcup_{\omega\in\Omega}A_\omega\quad A_\omega\in\Sigma$$
Especially, it is countable!