# Borel Measures: Atomic Decomposition

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

**Context**

The notion of atoms and point masses agree to certain extent.
*(See [Summary on Atoms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989196/79762).)*

Measures decompose w.r.t. atoms.
*(See [Paper on Atoms](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1970-025-03/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8/S0002-9939-1970-0279266-8.pdf).)*

Here, the goal is a direct approach to decompose w.r.t. point masses!

**Problem**

Consider a sigma-finite measure $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathbb{R}_+$.

Does it decompose into a discrete and a continuous part:
$$\mu=\mu_0+\mu_\infty$$
*(For a precise definition see corresponding paragraph of [Summary on Atoms](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/989196/79762).)*

**Attempt**

My sort of dumb idea is to simply subtract all discrete masses:
$$\mu_\infty:=\mu-\sum_{\#D\leq\aleph_0}\mu(D)$$
*(However, there are a loooot of double countings...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Decomposition**

Denote the collection of atoms by:
$$\mathcal{A}:=\{A\in\Sigma:A\text{ atom}\}$$

Identify common atoms:
$$A\sim A':\iff A\cap A'\in\mathcal{A}$$

Collect representatives:
$$A:=\bigcup_{[A]\in\mathcal{A}/\sim}A$$
*(By sigma-finiteness there can be at most countably many!)*

Construct atomic and atomless part:
$$\mu_a(E):=\mu(E\cap A)$$
$$\mu_c(E):=\mu(E\cap A)$$

**Remark**

For set atoms and point masses the proof follows the same lines!