# Fourier transform of a probability measure, and fourier transform of density

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I have defined, for a probability measure $\eta$ we have the fourier transform as $\hat{\eta} = \int e^{itx} \ d\eta(x)$, and for a function $h: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ we have that the fourier transform of $h$ is given by $\hat{h}(t) = \int e^{itx} h(x) \ dx$.

I then am told that the fourier transform of a probability measure, is the fourier transform of its density if it has one.

I don't really understand this statement - what is the density of a measurable function? I thought random variables are those to have densities. Any explanation please, thanks.

Comment: The concept of measurable functions is much more general/generic than that of a probability density function. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98801/probability-distribution-function-that-does-not-have-a-density-function), for example. [This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) discusses it a bit, and the common example of a random variable (or probability measure) without a density is the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution).

Comment: I have just never seen what a density of a measure $\eta$ is, only a density of a random variable, which is a measureable function.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are more familiar with the concept of [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem). Basically the "density" is just the RN-derivative in the context of probability (see the "Application" section on the linked wiki page).

The claim is stating that if you can write $d\eta(x)$ as $f(x) dx$, where $dx$ is the Lebesgue measure, then

$$ \hat \eta (t) = \int e^{itx} d\eta(x) = \int e^{itx} f(x) dx = \hat f(t) $$

Answer (score 3):

A random variable need not be continuous. A random variable is a measurable function
$$X:(\Omega,\mathscr{A})\to (\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B}).$$

A measurable function "transports" a measure from $(\Omega,\mathscr{A})$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$ as follow
$$\mathbb{P}_X(B)=\mathbb{P}(X\in B),\quad A\in\mathscr{B}.$$

Now for a measurable function $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, you can integrate the composition $u\circ X$ with respect to this image measure as follows
$$\int_{\Omega} u(X(\omega))\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}u(x)\mathbb{P}_X(dx).$$

Now a random variable is absolutely continuous, if its distribution, this image measure $\mathbb{P}_X$ is (absolutely) continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, meaning there exists a positive measurable, $\mathbb{P}_X$ almost everywhere uniqure $f$, such that:
$$\mathbb{P}_X(A)=\int_A f(x)\lambda(dx).$$
This $f$ is the density of $X$ or the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mathbb{P}_X$ with respect to $\lambda$.
Hence its characteristic function would be:
$$\phi_X(\xi):\mathbb{E}e^{i\xi X}=\int_\Omega e^{i\xi X(\omega)}\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=\int_\mathbb{R}  e^{i\xi x}\mathbb{P}_X(dx)=\int_\mathbb{R}e^{i\xi x}f(x)\lambda(dx).$$