# The distribution of a constant $a$ is Dirac mass in $a$, and it's density doesn't exist

Tags: probability-theory, dirac-delta, density-function

Let $X$ a real random variable with density $f_X$ and  $Y=g(X)$ with $g$ measurable.

I have some trouble understanding the following statement :

"
If $g(x)=a$ with $a$ a constant, for all $x$,  the distribution of $Y$ is the Dirac mass in $a$, which doesn't have a density
"

My questions :

1 - How can we translate this statement into formulas?

2 - Why doesn't the density exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\Pr)$ denote the probability space that serves as domain for random variable $X:\Omega\to \mathbb R$. Then $\{Y\in A\}=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid g(X(\omega))\in A\}=\Omega$ if $a\in A$ and $\{Y\in A\}=\varnothing$ otherwise.

1) Let $P_Y$ denote the probability meausure on $(\mathbb R,\mathcal B)$ prescribed by $A\mapsto\Pr(Y\in A)$.

That leads to:$$P_Y=\delta_a$$

This because $P_Y(A)=\Pr(Y\in A)=1$ if $a\in A$ and $P_Y(A)=\Pr(Y\in A)=0$ otherwise.

2) The distribution (it *exists* all right) will have function $F(x)=1_{[a,\infty)}(x)$ as cumulative distribution function. In order to have a density function the CDF must at least be continuous, which is not the case.

Comment: Very clear, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Unpack the variable $Y$:  If $c < d$ are real numbers, then
   $$
   P(c < Y < d) = P(c < g(X) < d) = P(c < a < d)
   $$
   This is 1 if $a$ is between $c$ and $d$, and $0$ if it isn't.
   So by extension, the distribution of $Y$ is identical to the distribution of a point mass centered at $a$:
   $$
      \mu_Y(E) = P(Y \subseteq E) = \begin{cases} 1 & a \in E \\ 0 & a \notin E \end{cases}
   $$
2. The *distribution* of $Y$ doesn't have a *density* function.  To see why, suppose it did have a density $f_Y$.  let $E$ be the set of numbers $\neq a$.  Then for any measurable set $E'\subseteq E$, 
   $$
       \int_{E'} f_Y\,dx = \mu_Y(E') = 0
   $$
   since $a \notin E'$.  This means that $f_Y = 0$ almost everywhere in $E$.
   Replacing $a$ (a set of measure zero by itself), we still have $f_Y = 0$ almost everywhere in $\mathbb{R}$.  But 
   $$
       \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_Y\,dx = \mu_Y(\mathbb{R}) = 1,
   $$
   a contradiction.

Comment: Very clear for the first point. In the second one, How did we conclude that $f_Y=0$ almost everywhere in $E$ implies that we still have that almost everywhere in $R$? thank you

Comment: @Daveddd: “almost everywhere” implies with respect to Lebesgue measure, and the Lebesgue measure of discrete sets (like singletons) is zero.  So if $F$ is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{a\right\}$ on which $f$ is nonzero, and $F'$ is the set of points of $\mathbb{R}$ on which $f$ is nonzero, the difference between $F'$ and $F$ is either the singleton $\left\{a\right\}$ or nothing at all. This means $F$ and $F'$ have the same Lebesgue measure.  We already showed $F$ has measure zero.

Comment: So this is the same as saying that $R \backslash  \{ a \}$ and $  \{ a \}$ are disjoint, so $\mu_Y(R)=\mu_Y(R \backslash  \{ a \})+\mu_Y( \{ a \})$, and since $\mu_Y( \{ a \}) = 0$ and $\mu_Y(R \backslash  \{ a \})=0$ then $\mu_Y( \{ a \})=0$. Thank you

Comment: @Daveddd: Not exactly.  $\mu_Y(\mathbb{R}) = \mu_Y(\{a\}) =1$.  The problem that (using $\lambda$ for Lebesgue measure) $\mu_Y(\{a\})=1$ while $\lambda(\{a\}) = 0$.  So $\mu_Y$ is not absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, which means it can't have a Radon-Nikodym derivative (i.e., density).   See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/98834/2785) to a related question.