# For a probability distribution, what is the most fundamental object : the probability density function or the cumulative distribution function?

Tags: probability

For a probability distribution, what is the most fundamental object :
the probability density function or the cumulative distribution function ?

Comment: CDF.  Not all distributions can be represented by a PDF.

Comment: The pdf may not exist but the cdf always exists . https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98801/probability-distribution-function-that-does-not-have-a-density-function

Comment: thanks a lot to the two of you for having shared these extremely useful informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly to exampnd on the great comments, which address this pretty well. More generally, if you get into a little measure theory, the CDF can be used to define the underlying probability*[measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics))* on the range of the random variable. Specifically -- the CDF assigns numbers to intervals in a consistent way whereas the density (if it exists) does not (you need to integrate it).

Therefore, the CDF is an example of a measure $\mu$ on half-open intervals $(-\infty,x]$ (in the one dimensional case).

In contrast, the density requires that the measure is differentiable. A more general version of the usual calculus derivative is the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), which handles cases where you are not restricted to the reals.